# Meteor server instancing

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am a bit confused about how meteor instances server code.

The way I thought it worked, was that when a client connects to the server, the server code is spawned for that session (so variables in the server code will change between users).

However, in testing, it appears that the server side code is one per all of the clients. Is this true? If so, how do I store variables specific to that client?

Comment: The authcast (http://meteor.com/authcast) covers this topic

Comment: Did you read documentation of [Publish and subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe)? It's a little different model but docs are descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this simple question: **yes, there is 1 instance of the server code at any given time, thus you should use Session. for your client side variables**.